# populating multiple html fields with specific values from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've got 2 pages, one where the user will input how many of each item they desire and then when button is clicked, the values will be stored to a mysql table and the page will redirect to the 'print-format page' where I want the most recent set of data to be displayed in the correct fields. So far i've got the inputted data to write to the database on the click of the button but I can't work out how to display it in the second page.

```
  //Default List Values
$whiteList = array(
    'orderLT' => '',
    'shopLT' => '',
    'orderLF' => '',
    'shopLF' => '',
    'orderLD' => '',
    'shopLD' => ''
);

//Add List quantities to Database
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO whiteList (orderLT,shopLT,orderLF,shopLF,orderLD,shopLD,orderLB,shopLB,orderSand,shopSand,orderLC,shopLC) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    $stmt->execute([ $_POST['orderLT'], $_POST['shopLT'], $_POST['orderLF'], $_POST['shopLF'], $_POST['orderLD'], $_POST['shopLD'], $_POST['orderLB'], $_POST['shopLB'], $_POST['orderSand'], $_POST['shopSand'], $_POST['orderLC'], $_POST['shopLC'] ]);
    header('Location: whiteprintable.php');
}
```

This allows the inputs to be added to the database

But despite trying lots of different examples on how to populate the next page with the corresponding values, it's not working properly?

there are multiple input fields on the first page (displayed in tables) all the same format as:

```
<th class="rowHeader" scope="row">Long Tin</th>
                                        <td><input type="number" class="listInput" id="orderLT" name="orderLT" value="<?=$whiteList['orderLT']?>" required></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" class="listInput" id="shopLT" name="shopLT" value="<?=$whiteList['shopLT']?>" required></td>
```

and I want it to populate the corresponding fields in the 'print format page'. I've tried this:

```
<input class="listInput" type="text" id="orderLT" name="orderLT" value="<?php echo $whiteLists[orderLT]?>"/>
```

with this in the php code at the top of the page :

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM whiteLists WHERE id >=MAX(id)');
$stmt->execute();
$whiteLists = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

but it doesn't work

Please could someone explain a good way to achieve this? :)

Comment: You need to be more specific than "doesn't work".  Wrong values? No values at all? Errors?   And so I understand, your first page gathers data from the input fields and will submit to the database. The second page you want to take those new values and display them onto the page?

Comment: @Phaelaxz the only error i'm finding is undefined constant orderLT and undefined index orderLT

Comment: <br /><b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant orderLT - assumed 'orderLT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/**file address**</b> on line <b>40</b><br /><br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: orderLT in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/**file address**</b> on line <b>40</b><br />

Comment: And yes I want it to work like you said

Comment: It's telling you it can't find a key called orderLT in $whiteLists. Does your table have columns with those names? Also, if your query has no results it won't have those columns either.  Have you verified your query returns any rows?

Comment: @Phaelaxz yes the table does have it as a column heading and no I haven't, I don't have much experience with either php or mysql sorry. how would I test if it returns any rows?

Comment: You can use count() to get the number of elements in the returned array or just dump the array onto the screen so you can see exactly what data you have. print_r($whiteLists);

Comment: @Phaelaxz I removed the 'Where id >= MAX(id)' from the Select * query and now it is outputting/ Array( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [orderLT] => 55 ........ ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [orderLT] => 33 .......... ). How do I get it to select the values for the most recent row (highest id or if I could get the date stored that would be good. I couldn't figure out how to do it ) and the display each quantity for the corresponding input box?

Comment: To get the row with the highest id, order by the ID in descending order (highest to lowest) and limit the returned results to 1 row.  SELECT * FROM whiteLists ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1